# DB2 400 Client IP Address function in SQL Query

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Is there a SQL function in DB2 400 that returns a client IP Address? The IP address of the client that executes the query

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

Create a User-Defined Function that would call a system API.

Use the [Retrieve Job Information (QUSRJOBI) API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fqusrjobi.htm), especially for DB2 Server jobs, which can tell you whether the SQL is being run in a "Server" job, and if so, what the client IPv4 or IPv6 address is.  See notes under JOBI0900 Format at API link given.  You can use QUSRJOBI format JOBI0600 for 5250-type interactive jobs, if IPv4 is being used.

Where you have an interactive job and IPv6 is being used you may need [Retrieve Device Description (QDCRDEVD) API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/QDCRDEVD.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing [special register](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzspecreg.htm) that holds the client ip address.  You may be able to create a stored procedure to call the job API to get that information.

Comment: From the list in that link, the CURRENT CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME can return remote IP address. (However, if the remote client doesn't supply the address, it won't be there.)

Answer (score 0):

No.

If the SQL is running from an interactive job you could write a stored procedure that would call [QDCRDEVD](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/QDCRDEVD.htm) and get the IP address that way.  If that doesn't fit your needs, perhaps you could share the nature of the business problem.  There may be a different way to approach the solution.

Comment: This API does not deal with server jobs, such as QZDASOINIT for ODBC connections, does it?

Comment: Haven't tested it nor QUSRJOBI.  One or the other ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

After read the docs for DB2 for IBM I, I thought it would be possible using the below SELECT with a Built-in global variable but the IP value I got back isn't my workstation IP. Then again, I'm at home going through company VPN and Firewall.

```
SELECT SYSIBM.CLIENT_IPADDR  
  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```